# Curves with negative self-intersection

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a non-singular projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Show that $S$ contains at most countably many irreducible curves $C$ with $C^2<0$.

Comment: Have you done any work on this yet? orcan you elaborate on your confusion?

Comment: @Rachmaninoff Well, I tried to get some relations between main invariants. From the adjunction formula, we have $C^2=2g(C)-2-K\cdot C$. Embedding $S$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$, we can also include the degree of $S$ in this relation, but I don't see what can I get from this.

Comment: "Embedding $S$ in  $\mathbb P^3$..." Actually you can't embed $S$ in $\mathbb P^3$ (in general).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key point is that if $C$ and $C'$ are distinct irreducible curves, then $C \cdot C' \geq 0$. Therefore if $C$ is an irreducible curve with $C^2<0$, it is the *unique* such curve in its numerical equivalence class.

Now the group $N^1(S)$ of numerical equivalence classes of curves on $S$ is a finitely-generated (hence countable) abelian group, by the ["theorem of the base"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%A9ron%E2%80%93Severi_group) of Severi and Néron.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to Asal's perfect answer let me remark that it is indeed possible for a smooth projective surface to carry infinitely many curves with negative self intersection.
Indeed, by blowing-up nine general points in $\mathbb P^2$ one obtains a surface $S$ containing infinitely many $(-1)$-curves i.e. curves $C$ isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$ and such that $C\cdot C=-1$.
Apparently this  was claimed by Franchetta who gave an incomplete argument and then proved by Nagata under an indication by Kodaira: see the original (and difficult to read) article [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250775912).
A more user-friendly proof can be found  on page 131, Proposition 22 of [Friedman's book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=_zqxhJSFO1AC&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Nice observation, Georges. Let me just add that another nice way to get such an example is to choose the 9 points not to be general, but rather the intersection of two cubic curves. Then the blowup has the structure of an elliptic fibration over $\mathbf P^1$, and the group structure on the generic fibre gives a way to produce infinitely many $(-1)$-curves starting from the 9 exceptional divisors.

Comment: Thanks, Asal, I'll think about your comment. I really admire your mastership of classical algebraic geometry.